# Laravel 4: Unique(database) not validating

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel-4, unique

I am creating a basic CMS to teach myself the fundamentals of Laravel and PHP.

I have a 'pages' table and I am storing a url_title. I want this URL title to be unique for obvious reasons. However, whatever I do to validate it, fails. It just saves anyway. I'm sure it is something simple. Can you spot what is wrong with this code?

I am also using Former in the view, that doesn't validate either. I have tried hard-coding a value as the last option in the unique method and it fails also. 
http://anahkiasen.github.io/former/

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique 
States: unique:table,column,except,idColumn

Here is my Controller:

```
public function store()
{
    $validation = Pages::validate(Input::all());

    if($validation->fails()) {
      Former::withErrors($validation);
      return View::make('myview');
    } else {
        Pages::create(array(
            'title'             => Input::get('title'),
            'url_title'         => Input::get('url_title'),
            'status'            => Input::get('status'),
            'body'              => Input::get('body'),
            'seo_title'         => Input::get('seo_title'),
            'seo_description'   => Input::get('seo_description')
        ));

        //check which submit was clicked on
        if(Input::get('save')) {
            return Redirect::route('admin_pages')->with('message', 'Woo-hoo! page was created successfully!')->with('message_status', 'success');
        }
        elseif(Input::get('continue')) {
            $id = $page->id;
            return Redirect::route('admin_pages_edit', $id)->with('message', 'Woo-hoo! page was created successfully!')->with('message_status', 'success');
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my model:

```
class Pages extends Eloquent {

   protected $guarded = array('id');

   public static $rules = array(
        'id'            => 'unique:pages,url_title,{{$id}}'
   );

   public static function validate($data) {
       return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
   }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
 public static $rules = array(
    //      'id'=> 'unique:pages,url_title,{{$id}}'
    //      'id'=> 'unique:pages,url_title,$id'
    //      'id'=> 'unique:pages,url_title,:id'
    //      'id'=> 'unique:pages,url_title,'. {{$id}}
    //      'id'=> 'unique:pages,url_title,'. $id
 );
```

Any ideas? I spoke to the guy who created Former. He can't make head nor tail about it either. He suggested tracking it back to find our what query Laravel uses to check the uniqueness and try running that directly in my DB to see what happens. I can't find the query to do this. Does anyone know where to track it down?

Many thanks

Comment: use an unique column in the database so that it fails on duplication?.... if nothing works, atleast it can keep the integrity.

Comment: Thanks itachi. I'm not sure I follow. I'm trying to use the ID, which is unique to test against and I want the url_title to be unique also. Does that make sense?

Comment: if the id column is auto increment, then it will be unique either way (means no need to test against id). all you need to see if the slug is unique or not.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Would that work with updating an entry? I guess I can just use some different rules. Thanks itachi. I'm pretty new to this, so all the help I can get is very much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: why don't you use the plain old laravel basic validations?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'url_title' => 'unique:pages,url_title,{{$id}}'
);
```

As I guessed from your code `Input::get('url_title')`
You have to use the `field` name used in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks peeps. I have been using the Laravel unique solutions and it hasn't been working well. I found this package which solves the issue brilliantly.

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#eloquent

Definitely worth a look.

Thanks for your feedback.